# Get currently active AudioSessions or AudioOutput

Tags: android, audio-player, audiosession, android-music-player

I'm trying to create a Visualizer with the [Visualizer Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html). The documentation says to use "0" as session id to get the audio output, however this seems to be deprecated and only results in an error.

I searched for ways to get the currently active AudioSession ID's but can't find anything that remotely helps me out. All samples only provide info on how to do it with playing music by yourself, but I want to use it for visualizing Spotify and other music or videos being played, so that's not an option for me.

I know that it IS possible. There are apps like HueManic that work completely fine. I just can't find any information on how it would be still possible.

Comment: Did you manage to figure that out? Trying to make an Equalizer app that can modify sound of other app, but had no luck so far figuring out how to apply the effect to an audio session from other apps. And it's definitely possible, since there is are similar apps working just fine